# Script does not get variable using ajax function onClick, and $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am passing a variable through href using onClick

> script1.php

```
<td><a  href="#top_opps" onClick="test('hello');" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['listings_views']; ?></a></td>
```

And this is my ajax code

> Ajax function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function test(x){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "folder1/folder2/script2.php",
    data: "var=x",
    success: function(e){
    }
  });
 };
 </script>
```

But When I want to get the var value

> script2.php

```
 <?php
 $variable = $_POST['var'];
 echo $variable;
 ?>
```

The variable is empty

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you read correctly his question, "The variable is empty" so he is not able to get it. The syntax is not correct, look at my answer

Comment: @GuillaumeLehezee `"var="+x` is the same as `{var:x}`

Comment: I didn't know that sorry :s I never tried this way and was simply looking at official Jquery docs. So... sorry xD

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct, try with this JQUERY :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function test(x){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "folder1/folder2/script2.php",
    data: { var: x },
    success: function(e){
    }
  });
 }
 </script>
```

See exemples on [JQUERY website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You added `x` as part of your string and not a variable. Should be,

```
function test(x){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "folder1/folder2/script2.php",
    data: "var="+x, // or data:{var:x},
    success: function(e){
    }
  });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your function:

```
function test(x){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "folder1/folder2/script2.php",
    data: "var=x", <-- change into "var="+x otherwise $_POST['var'] will be "x"
    // or {var:x} will also work
    success: function(e){
    }
  });
 }; <-- no semi-colon needed here
```